# CakePHP and Plugins

Tags: cakephp

I need to create plugins that hook into the functionality of my main application. CakePHP plugins only instantiate themselves when its own controller is called meaning I cannot affect the processes of my main application.

```
mainapp/action2baffected
myplugin/
```

I like the idea of having self contained pluggable models , is there any other way to get this to work? Creating models on the fly etc or write a plugin system from scratch with no cakeiness!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use components and behaviors (from the plugins) into your core application. There is one very good presentation of Pierre MARTIN [Using reusing-plugins](http://www.slideshare.net/real34/using-reusingplugins). It's a really inspirational resource.

Comment: Currently using App:import to include the plugins app_controller at runtime and using the constructClasses() to fully instantiate it. Seems to work great right now.

Comment: woodscreative, could you elaborate on how you got this to work? I'm trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

We have put quite a lot of work into making plugins truly self contained in [Infinitas](https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas)
You can have a look at some of the methods that are used, but the main code is in the [events](https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/tree/dev/core/events/). Everything from cache configs, db connections and include assets like css/js are done from within the plugin, even injecting some markup into views is handled.